# How to check if object is sql to linq type

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

anyone know if there's any easy way to check if an object is an sql to linq type? I have a method like this but would like it to only accept valid types.

```
public static void Update(params object[] items)
{
    using (TheDataContext dc = new TheDataContext())
    {
        System.Data.Linq.ITable table;

        if(items.Length > 0)
            table = dc.GetTable(items[0].GetType());

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            table.Attach(items[i]);
            dc.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, 
                items[i]);
        }

        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to access the [MetaModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metamodel.aspx) instance returned from the [Mapping property on the DataContext instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.mapping.aspx).

With that, you can call the [GetTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metamodel.gettable.aspx) method, passing the Type of the model that you want to determine is supported in your current LINQ-to-SQL scenario.

Note, this is just in the *model*, if you want to check for it's existence in the database, then that's a different story, you will have to handle that yourself.  However, that's not too difficult.  From the [MetaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metatable.aspx) instance returned from GetTable, you can use the [TableName property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metatable.tablename(v=VS.90).aspx) to get the name of the table as it exists in the database, and then query the database for the existence of the table, as per the mapping on the model.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what i'm looking for is something to replace object with in Update(params object[] items) so that it's only possible to use linq tables as parameters.

Comment: @remado: I don't understand what you mean.  The answer I gave gives you the mechanisms by which you can check the types of your objects to make sure that they can be used with LINQ.